# Set matplotlib legend out of the plot by default

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/3128336) shows how to put the matplotlib's legend out of the plot and want to set this code as a default.

```
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

[matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#legends) shows a way to set `loc` but not `bbox_to_anchor`.

```
mpl.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'center left'              # this works
mpl.rcParams['legend.bbox_to_anchor'] = (1.0, 0.5)      # this does not work
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The answer is essentially: No!